# Build Errors C++ Visual Studio 2022

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio-2022, build-error

I'm trying to implement a resizable array class in C++. I started out with a basic C++ Console Application Template.
I'm unable to build the basic Hello World program in Visual Studio 2022.
This is all the code in my main.cpp file-

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    std::cout << "Hello World!\n";
    return 0;
}
```

And [these](https://pastebin.com/FDkXbUjJ) are my build logs for the above project.

Comment: I think you corrupted this file from your windows SDK: `C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.19041.0\ucrt\corecrt_memcpy_s.h`

Comment: Go back to the installer and reinstall the SDK

Comment: @drescherjm Reinstalled the complete c++ development kit
https://pastebin.com/Hd07HEdy new error log

Comment: Looks the same. You may have to ask Microsoft.

Comment: One thing that is odd is my: `corecrt_memcpy_s.h` file starts with a comment on the first line (although I have a different / older sdk installed). Your errors seem to indicate that there is no comment on the first line of this file for you.

Comment: Oh well, thanks for your help. Posting the same on the Microsoft Dev Community.